# Adicionar propriedades ao elemento [Node]

Tags: javascript, dom, propriedade

Há algum problema em adicionar propriedades personalizadas diretamente no elemento [Node]? Por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('minhaDiv').minhaPropriedade = 'teste';
```

Estou utilizando o Firefox e não tive problemas quanto a setar ou obter a propriedade, mas é algo que devo evitar? Por quê?

Comment: [Aqui](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) você pode ver um artigo muito interessante sobre o assunto.

Comment: Oeslei, eu escrevi a minha resposta um pouco rápido. Acho que seria melhor deixar para aceitar uma resposta mais tarde, para incentivar que sejam postadas outras respostas, potencialmente mais completas. Mais sobre isso no meta: [Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/494/74)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É algo que geralmente se recomenda evitar. Principal motivo: você pode acabar causando uma colisão de nome com uma propriedade que venha a ser futuramente implementada no DOM. Então, mesmo que hoje o código não cause nenhum problema, no futuro ele pode vir a causar.

Outro aspecto é que isso é meio caminho andado para mais tarde você ter vontade de estender o DOM, isto é, estender os protótipos de objetos nativos do DOM como `HTMLElement`. Isso não é uma boa ideia pois esses objetos são muito mais suscetíveis a peculiaridades que variam de acordo com a implementação – e é a própria especificação da linguagem que [dá essa liberdade](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) aos implementadores dos chamados *host objects*.

Para maiores detalhes sobre tudo isso, a grande referência é o seguinte artigo do Kangax: [*What's wrong with extending the DOM?*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) Embora o artigo seja de 2010, quando o panorama dos browsers era outro, a especificação da linguagem não mudou (ainda), então boa parte do que está dito lá continua válido – exceto, talvez, pelas análises de performance e de bugs específicos de determinados browsers.

Comment: Nota: agora sim a especificação já mudou. Talvez esteja na hora de toda essa discussão ser reavaliada.