# É recomendado utilizar prototype em objetos nativos?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Eu acho muito bom a ideia de ter os meus próprios métodos importados para os Objetos nativos do javascript.

Como por exemplo:

```
String.prototype.hello = function(){
     return this.toString() + ' hello';
}

'Say '.hello() // say hello

Number.prototype.add = function(){
   return this + 1;
}

(1).add() // 2
```

Mas essa prática é recomendada?

Existe alguma desvantagem em fazer isso? Ou seria uma prática melhor criar meu próprio objeto?

Comment: Duplicata? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48070/adicionar-propriedades-ao-elemento-node Mesmo que não seja, creio que o mesmo raciocínio da minha resposta se aplique.

Comment: Muito útil, @bfavaretto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como todas as perguntas de estilo de programação, não há uma resposta 100% certa nesse caso mas eu não sou muito fã de adicionar métodos a objetos nativos.

- O prototype dos métodos nativos tem escopo global. Se dois módulos do seu projeto tentarem sobrescrever um mesmo método pode haver conflito.
- Pode ser que uma versão futura do seu Browser passe a implementar alguns dos métodos que você sobrescreveu. Por exemplo, muita gente teve dor de cabeça quando os browsers passaram a implementar o `forEach` em vetores porque a implementação nativa é sutilmente diferente da implementação que as bibliotecas adcionavam.
- Métodos inseridos por você no prototype podem aparecer quando você itera no objeto com um loop `for in`. Isso pode quebrar código que não esperava a presença desses métodos e é particularmente inconveniente no caso do Object.prototype, já que é comum usar for-in em tabelas de hash.
- A vantagem de se implementar algo como método ao invés de como uma função em uma biblioteca separada é que o dispatching é dinâmico e podemos aproveitar isso se implementarmos um método com o mesmo nome em mais de uma classe. No entanto, em muitos casos (como seus exemplos de add e hello) os métodos não são genéricos e só fazem sentido em uma única classe. Nesse case acho que a notação bonitinha de `x.metodo()` ao invés de `LIB.metodo(x)` não compensa quebrar o princípio da responsabilidade única.

A exceção na minha opinião é quando editamos o prototype para adicionar métodos que existem nas versões recentes dos browsers mas que não existiam em versões antigas. Isso serve para aumentar a compatibilidade do seu programa com browsers antigos e não vai contra os primeiros dois itens da minha lista pois só estamos inserindo métodos que sabemos que nunca irão causar conflito. Dito isso, sugiro usar implementaçoẽs existentes como o projeto [es5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) ao invés de reimplementar as coisas na mão. Alguns detalhes são bem sutis.